# Project a word on an axis of similarity between 2 words

Tags: vector, data-visualization, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I am using Word2Vec for word embeddings. I want to project a word W on an axis which represent the similarity of the word W to two given word W1 and W2 in a way that we can see to which word W is more similiar to, like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NpB5.jpg)

What is the best way to do it?